# ssis oledb source, as400 parameter not found

Tags: ssis

I'm using ssis 2008 and I'm trying to get data from an as400 database.

I have a Data Flow Task, and inside it, I have an Oledb Source and in there, I have Data access mode to Sql Command, and I have a  query:

```
select *
from table1
where name = ?
```

Then i click on the Parameters button and set "name1" for the name of my parameter.
When i ran the ssis, i got error:

> Error: The SQL command requires a parameter named ""00001"", which is
>   not found in the parameter mapping.

So I changed the parameter name to ""00001"" and the ssis worked fine.

Now, the problem is that this same ssis needed to be ran on another as400 server, and older one, and when it ran it showed error:

> Error: The SQL command requires a parameter named "", which is
>   not found in the parameter mapping.

So, now the other server requires a different parameter name.

Is there another way of doing this process using something different than Oledb Source in order to avoid the problem?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems to be an as400 bug, as seen here : [link]http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/5d6ef4f9-1a67-45d1-8a49-eb08becf1408/

On that thread a user says: "This bug is directly related to IBMDA400 from IBM Client Access Tools.  There is a bug with the driver passing a parameter to the AS/400.  I have proved this out using a third party driver from HiT Software.  Passing 00001 is correct using their drivers."

So as I see, it wont matter the method you use, what's need to be done in order to get it working is to pass the parameter with name that AS400 requires. If the parameter with the correct name is passed then the query will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We are using sql 2012 and a as400 system and we use a ODBC source for the as400. For our setup it seems to be working. So try the ODBC.

Comment: So, I would create an ODBC source for the as400 in Windows by going to Control Panel----Administrative tools------Data Sources(ODBC) and setting the ODBC Source there. But which Data Flow Source should I use on the Dataflow?

Comment: Use the ODBC you created in windows in the 'Connection Manager' and then use the ODBC in the Data flow.

Comment: "Use the ODBC you created in windows in the 'Connection Manager'" ....this part is ok, but......on the Data Flow tab, if you click on the toolbox menu there are the Data flow sources, I can see 6 data sources but I don't see ODBC. Where is this ODBC you are talking about?

Comment: I think it may be because of 2008. because I see here in 2012 that there are 8 sources so they must have added it only now.

Comment: Maybe you can try this link. Might be helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/80ecabce-d009-4f3e-ae4d-6c8a0549e6b4/

Comment: This seems to be an as400 bug. I have created an answer for my question. Thanks for the help!